# Slider component has been extracted from the React Native core and will be removed

Tags: react-native, slider

The warning states that the Slider component has been extracted from the React Native core and will be removed in a future release. It suggests installing and importing the Slider component from `@react-native-community/slider` instead of `react-native`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: `/Volumes/code/projects/mobile/yourAppName/node_modules/react-native-color-picker/dist/HoloColorPicker.js`

and delete `Slider` that is imported from `react-native` and add this:

`import Slider from "@react-native-community/slider";`

Do the same for:

`/Volumes/code/projects/mobile/yourAppName/node_modules/react-native-color-picker/src/HoloColorPicker.tsx`